Solving a second order linear differential equation by reducing order
I'm trying to solve to the following ODE:
$$ u''(t) - u'(t) (1 + u(t) ) = 0 $$
So I start by making the following substitution:
$$ u'(t) = \frac{du}{dt} =  w(u) $$
$$ u''(t) = \frac{dw}{du} \frac{du}{dt} = \frac{dw}{du} w(u) = w'(u) w(u) $$
Plugging those into the original ODE and rearranging some terms:
$$ w'w - w = uw $$
Now solving this ODE is supposed to be easier:
$$ w ( w' - (u+1)) = 0 $$
Which gives 2 solutions, a trivial one, $ w_1(u)=0$, and the following
$$ \frac{dw}{du} - (u+1) = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{dw}{du} = u+1 $$
Integrating both sides
$$ w(u) = \frac{u^2}{2} + u + C $$
Now we got a Bernoulli equation, and I want to reduce its order using $w = z'$, but its not working because of the constant $C$ and I'm instead getting
$$ z' = -z - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{C}{z^2} $$
What am I doing wrong here?

To explicit Yves Daoust's comment, since $w = u'$, you have $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\frac{1}{2}u^2 + u + C} = t + D$$ by separation of the variables, where $D$ is another constant.

Ohhh I totally missed that! Thank you so much!:)

$$u(t)=\sqrt{2 C-1}\cdot \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 C-1}\cdot (D+t)\right)-1$$
